# Number of Elements in a Struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I am new to C and I would like to know the size of an array of structs. I tried to use sizeof but it didn't work.

```
typedef struct Voitures{
    char categorie[20];
    char marque[15];
    char model[15];
    char boite[12];
    unsigned short int prix;
    unsigned short int qtt;
} Voiture;

Voiture liste_voitures[];

int main(){

    //elements added to liste_voitures[]

    prinft("%d", sizeof(liste_voitures)/sizeof(liste_voitures[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: sizeof works, show what you tried. liste_voitures BTW has size 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

aha your edit makes it clearer now

If list_voitures is supposed to be a dynamically size array then you cannot find it out this way

The `sizeof(lv)/sizeof(lv[0])` only works for fixed size array. In your case you created a zero size array so got the answer 0. If you do instead

```
 Voiture liste_voitures[10];
```

you will get 10.

*But* you want a dynamic array I think. You will have to keep track of the size yourself

Plus have

```
Voiture *liste_voitures;
```

which is a pointer to a voiture